# how to break from $.each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery loop where I am slicing the json array upto 5 and now I need to check whether the key value is empty or not.
Once I check for 5 elements,if my condition works then it will print 5 data but what if it doesn't?
It shows me same amount of time the else.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$.each(data.slice(0,5), function(key, value) {
              if(value.emailID!="")
              {
                $("#result-success").append("<p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>"+value.fullName+"<span>"+value.emailID+"</span></a></p>").addClass('before-search-message');
                $("#loader_gif").hide();    
              }
              else
              {
                $("#loader_gif").hide();
                $("#search-btn").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#result-success").append("<p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>No Records Found!</span></a></p>").addClass('before-search-message'); 
              }
             });
```

If my emailID is blank for all array elements, then it appends for 5 times with message "No records found" any solution to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let found = false;
$.each(data.slice(0,5), function(key, value) {

              if(value.emailID!="")
              {
                $("#result-success").append("<p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>"+value.fullName+"<span>"+value.emailID+"</span></a></p>").addClass('before-search-message');
                $("#loader_gif").hide();
                found = true;
              }
             });

if(!found){

                $("#loader_gif").hide();
                $("#search-btn").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#result-success").append("<p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>No Records Found!</span></a></p>").addClass('before-search-message'); 

}
```

Comment: but I have json array and need to check in an array for all values

Comment: Sorry @jaymin_has_void_senseof_humour; I don't get your point. What will prevent you to do it with the code above? Since you want the `else` to be executed only when "no records our found", you have to do that outside your loop.

Comment: can you please give us json array.

Answer (score 2):

```
return false; = break;

return true; or return; = continue;
```

From Jquery Docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i think,

```
var valid = false;
$.each(data.slice(0,5), function(key, value) {
    if(value.emailID!="") {
        $("#result-success").append("<p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>"+value.fullName+"<span>"+value.emailID+"</span></a></p>").addClass('before-search-message');
        $("#loader_gif").hide();
        valid = true;
}
});

if (!valid) {
    $("#loader_gif").hide();
    $("#search-btn").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#result-success").append("<p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>No Records Found!</span></a></p>").addClass('before-search-message');
}
```

I hope It's what you want.

Comment: same answer as a above, you just used var instead of let. But worked thanks

Comment: @lee this answer is similar to the one I posted

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasData =false
$.each(data.slice(0,5), function(key, value)     {
          if(value.emailID!="")
          {
           hasData = true
            $("#result-success").append("<p><a   href='javascript:void(0)'>"+value.fullName+"<span>"+value.emailID+"</span></a></p>").addClass('before-search-message');
            $("#loader_gif").hide();    
          }

         });
       if(!hasData){
          $("#loader_gif").hide();
            $("#search-btn").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#result-success").append("<p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>No  Records Found!</span></a></enter code herep>").addClass('before-search-message');}
```

This is probably what you’re looking for. You were iterating over display no results 5 times

Comment: @abe this answer is similar to the one I posted

Comment: @edkeveked When I started writing the answer I hadn’t seen any answers yet. I only saw afterwards. Sorry about that.